# Read all the text files in a folder in box.com with python

Tags: python

I am wondering anyone have a source or ways to get the files in box.com?
I am sorry, I do not know how to start because all the guidelines from the website only for uploading files to folder in box.com and not read the files from folder in box.com.

For example, in my box.com, I have a folder named "test"

Comment: there is an SDK https://github.com/box/box-python-sdk

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, I will check it right away.

Comment: Hi sir, sorry, I followed the guideline to get the client ID, developers token and also the secret key. But it is only to get authorization, right? How can I load the files in the folder for certain link in the box.com?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately I did this last week.
Try this,

```
oauth = OAuth2(
           client_id=your_client_id,
           client_secret=your_client_secret,
           access_token=your_access_token,
           refresh_token=your_refresh_token
        )
client = Client(oauth)
all_folder = client.folder(folder_id='0').get_items(limit=None)

for folder in all_folder:
   if folder.name == 'test':     //Here we're searching for specific folder
      all_files = client.folder(folder_id=folder.object_id).get()['item_collection']['entries']
```

This code will help you to get files from folder in Box

Comment: Hi sir! I managed to print the list of files in the folder but I could not read the file. I do not want to download to my local but just want to stream read the data into json file since it was a json file. Is it possible?